# Changing radius of a layout using seekBar in Android

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I need to change radius of all four corners of a layout using SeekBar. How can I do that?

I know I can create a layout with round corners using XML, but I need to do it at runtime using SeekBar.

Answer (score 1):

```
        GradientDrawable shapeDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    shapeDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    shapeDrawable.setCornerRadius(100f);
    shapeDrawable.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    shapeDrawable.setBounds(0,0,600,600);
    svMain.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set radius for Drawables but for layouts or Views directly. The only exception (for I know) is CardViews, which have radius as an attribute.

If it is a CardView, you can easily change its radius dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your layout inside a **cardview** and change its `radius` using

```
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
```

simple trick....